# bash + while loop with regular expression

Tags: linux, bash, regular-expression

The following loop is looping when number is less than 1 or greater than 45
but it fails when the answer includes special characters such as [ % & *  # ] etc

What can I change in the code in order to support this issue?

```
a=1
b=45


while [[ $answer -lt $a ]] || [[ $answer -gt $b ]]
do

echo -n "please answer"
read answer
done
```

Comment: Why would the answer have special characters?

Comment: sorry - update it

Comment: Actually, the only thing that code snippet produces is an error:

`please answer./numfail.sh: line 11: read: answer$': not a valid identifier`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might rethink the whole concept. This is a simple snippet that will get you going.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

a=1
b=45


while read -p 'Please answer: ' answer
do
   re=$(printf '%s\n' "$answer" | tr -dc '[[:digit:]]')
   if ((re < a || re > b)); then
       read -p 'Please answer: ' $re
   else
       echo "Loop ended"
       exit 
   fi
 done
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
a=1
b=45
#
while [[ $answer -lt $a || $answer -gt $b ]]; do

read -p "please answer: " answer
answer=$(echo "$answer" | tr -dc '[:alnum:]\n\r')

done
```

The `answer=$(echo "$answer" | tr -dc '[:alnum:]\n\r')` line will strip any special characters from the answer and reset the variable to the new value.

Comment: i prefer to continue the loop in case integer include characters as & or % etc

Comment: see val0x00ff answers , he have nice solution

Comment: @yael did some update but, not sure what your goal is.